# How can I resize a single row in DevExpress XtraGrid (Winforms)?

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, devexpress

When I try to resize a single row, all rows are resized, I want to make sure that only a single row is resized when I use my pointer to increase row's height. Can anyone tell me how to accomplish that? I'm using DevExpress DXperience 12.1.

Comment: there's no code to be shown, the grid has properties, AllowRowSizing and RowAutoHeight. Setting AllowRowSizing to "true" enables the user to click and resize the row of the gridview but, when the row is droped, all rows in the gridview are resized; that's something I want to prevent from happening. Just like Excel, only the row, I'm trying to resize with the pointer, should change its size, instead of having all the rows resized accordingly. I hope I could clarify the situation here.

Comment: Resizing the height of only one row means resizing the whole control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer to this question from DevExpress.
[DevExpress Support](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q450528)